# API Gateway HTTP CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have a backend which exposes a normal http server at `mydomain.com`. I wanted to have a secured endpoint so I decided to create an API Gateway endpoint that redirects the traffic to my domain endpoint.

When I do so, I lose all my CORS headers that are exposed by the backend. So if send a request directly to the backend, I get the following response which contains the CORS headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, POST, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 20:03:03 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
foo: bar

Hello World
```

but when I request to the API Gateway endpoint, I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 20:03:09 GMT
apigw-requestid: KbRzrjEvjoEEMHQ=
foo: bar
```

I tried setting up those CORS headers in API Gateway Cors panel but without luck.

This is the part in the backend when I set up the CORS headers.

```js
app.addListener('request', (req, res) => {
  const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 300, // 30 days
    'foo': 'bar'
    /** add other headers as per requirement */
  };

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.writeHead(204, headers);
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  if (['GET', 'POST'].indexOf(req.method) > -1) {
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end('Hello World');
    return;
  }

  res.writeHead(405, headers);
  res.end(`${req.method} is not allowed for the request.`);
})
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using a proxy or non-proxy HTTP integration with API Gateway?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61215324/api-gw-options-pre-flight-request-removes-my-cors-headers

I will comment if I find a way to solve it. In contact with AWS support. I am sending this question to them also.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem before;

If the response is sent via a proxy integration, it will preserve it.

Else, the CORS headers will need to be configured in APIGateway. In the dropdown, you can "Enable CORS" and set the required headers, or set it up as proxy integration.

Answer (score 0):

Either use proxy integration or enable CORS.

Proxy:
[image]

CORS:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]